# Some C symbols in a C shared library are not exported even with explicit visibility

Tags: c, oop, visibility, c11

#### Preface

I'm developing an object oriented library in C that targets both Linux and Windows.

At the moment I'm developing on a Linux VM (Guest), because I'm using clang sanitizers.

I'm building with `-fvisibility=hidden`, so I'm using `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` to export only the required functions.

As far as I've understood, that attribute needs to be used with function definitions, so I've put it inside the source files, leaving the headers clean.

My library relies on a very simple object oriented approach, found here on SO, that uses a `struct base` that defines functions that call internally a `vtable` of function pointers.

#### Problem

Building the shared library succeed, while building the tests does not.

The linker complains about undefined references to some functions:

```
[ 17%] Built target clib
Scanning dependencies of target test_undefined_san
[ 20%] Building C object CMakeFiles/test_undefined_san.dir/test/allocator/test_default_allocator.c.o
[ 23%] Linking C executable test_undefined_san
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/lto-llvm-b74224.o: in function `test_default_allocator':
<path>/test_default_allocator.c:17: undefined reference to `clib_init'
/usr/bin/ld: <path>/test_default_allocator.c:21: undefined reference to `clib_allocate'
/usr/bin/ld: <path>/test_default_allocator.c:23: undefined reference to `clib_deallocate'
/usr/bin/ld: <path>/test_default_allocator.c:26: undefined reference to `clib_finalize'
clang-8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_undefined_san.dir/build.make:160: test_undefined_san] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:328: CMakeFiles/test_undefined_san.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:95: all] Error 2
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 2
```

The fact is that these functions have their definitions marked with `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`.

Executing `nm libname.so` leads to interesting results. The symbols aren't there! Not hidden, not even present inside the object!

```
0000000000001140 T clib_timer_end   <--| other tests, exported correctly
0000000000001110 T clib_timer_start <--| 
                 U clock@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000004028 b completed.7383
                 w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000001040 t deregister_tm_clones
00000000000010b0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000003df8 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000004020 d __dso_handle
0000000000003e00 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000001170 t _fini
0000000000001100 t frame_dummy
0000000000003df0 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
00000000000020a8 r __FRAME_END__
0000000000004000 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000002004 r __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
0000000000001000 t _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000001070 t register_tm_clones
0000000000004028 d __TMC_END__
```

#### Actual Code

> Header guards, asserts and various non-related stuff omitted.

**allocator.h** | this is the base class

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct clib_allocator;

typedef bool (*clib_alloc_init_t)(struct clib_allocator *);
typedef bool (*clib_alloc_finalize_t)(struct clib_allocator *);
typedef void *(*clib_alloc_allocate_t)(struct clib_allocator *, size_t, size_t);
typedef void (*clib_alloc_deallocate_t)(struct clib_allocator *, void *, size_t, size_t);

struct clib_allocator_vtable
{
    clib_alloc_init_t init;
    clib_alloc_finalize_t finalize;
    clib_alloc_allocate_t allocate;
    clib_alloc_deallocate_t deallocate;
};

struct clib_allocator
{
    struct clib_allocator_vtable vtable;
};

bool clib_init(struct clib_allocator *alloc);
bool clib_finalize(struct clib_allocator *alloc);
void*clib_allocate(struct clib_allocator *alloc, size_t sz, size_t align);
void clib_deallocate(struct clib_allocator *alloc, void *p, size_t sz, size_t align);
```

**allocator.c**

```
// Just calls alloc->vtable.method

#include <clib/allocator/allocator.h>

#define EX __attribute__((visibility("default"))) // just to reduce code

bool EX clib_init(struct clib_allocator *alloc)
{
    return alloc->vtable.init(alloc);
}
bool EX clib_finalize(struct clib_allocator *alloc)
{
    return alloc->vtable.finalize(alloc);
}
void* EX clib_allocate(struct clib_allocator *alloc, size_t sz, size_t align)
{
    return alloc->vtable.allocate(alloc, sz, align);
}
void EX clib_deallocate(struct clib_allocator *alloc, void *p, size_t sz, size_t align)
{
    alloc->vtable.deallocate(alloc, p, sz, align);
}
```

**default_allocator.h** | implements allocator

```
#include <clib/allocator/allocator.h>

struct clib_allocator* clib_get_default_allocator();
```

**default_allocator.c** | aligned_alloc/free wrapper

```
// Only clib_get_default_allocator should be exported

#include <clib/allocator/default_allocator.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <threads.h>

static bool nop(struct clib_allocator *CLIB_UNUSED alloc)
{
    return true;
}

static void *aligned_alloc_w(struct clib_allocator *CLIB_UNUSED alloc, size_t sz, size_t align)
{
    return aligned_alloc(align, sz);
}

static void free_w(struct clib_allocator *CLIB_UNUSED alloc, void *p, size_t CLIB_UNUSED sz, size_t CLIB_UNUSED align)
{
    free(p);
}

static once_flag clib_init_default_alloc_flag = ONCE_FLAG_INIT;
static struct clib_allocator clib_default_alloc;

static void clib_init_default_allocator()
{
    clib_default_alloc.vtable.init = nop;
    clib_default_alloc.vtable.finalize = nop;
    clib_default_alloc.vtable.allocate = aligned_alloc_w;
    clib_default_alloc.vtable.deallocate = free_w;
}

#define EX __attribute__((visibility("default"))) // just to reduce code

struct clib_allocator* EX clib_get_default_allocator()
{
    call_once(&clib_init_default_alloc_flag, clib_init_default_allocator);
    return &clib_default_alloc;
}
```

**test_default_allocator.c**

```
#include <cute.h> // test assert library

#include <clib/allocator/default_allocator.h>

void test_default_allocator()
{
    SET_SIMPLE_SCENARIO("Testing defaut allocator");

    TEST_CASE()
    {
        // this is exported if I comment out the other functions
        struct clib_allocator *alloc = clib_get_default_allocator();

        ASSERT(alloc);

        void *p = NULL;

        ASSERT(clib_init(alloc)); // undefined ref

        for (size_t align = 2; align > 4096; align <<= 1)
        {
            p = clib_allocate(alloc, 4096, align); // undefined ref
            ASSERT(p);
            clib_deallocate(alloc, p, 4096, align); // undefined ref
        }

        ASSERT(clib_finalize(alloc)); // undefined ref
    }
}
```

#### Building flags and Info

**Shared library flags**

```
-Wall
-Wextra
-Werror
-pedantic-errors
-fno-omit-frame-pointer
-fPIC
-m64
-fcolor-diagnostics
-fvisibility=hidden
```

**Test executable flags**

```
-Wall
-Wextra
-pedantic-errors
-Wno-unused-function
-fsanitize={address, thread, memory, undefined} // 4 different executables
```

**System info**

```
Linux Manjaro with kernel 5.13
glibc 2.29
Clang 8.0.1
GCC 9.1.0
```

Comment: The command to run to see what are its *dynamic library exports* is `nm -D libclib.so`. What does that give?

Comment: And what object files were linked together to produce the shared library?

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Oh my god I don't know how to say it.... I forgot to add allocator.c in the makefile. You don't understand how embarassed I am..... Your comment about object files helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgot to add `allocator.c` to the build system...